# Using set listchars, what are 'extends' and 'precedes'?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Searching for a solution to show hidden characters, I found the example,

```
:set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
:set list
```

What are `extends` and `precedes`?

I expected a file to have only tabs, but these options show some spaces as `>` rather than `>-`.

[How to Display Hidden Characters in vim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74485/how-to-display-hidden-characters-in-vim)

Comment: I wanted to use `hidden-characters`  for a tag, but it's not there and I'm not 150 reputation (>_<)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extends and Precedes are used when you don't have line wrapping on, to show that there is more text to the left or right of the line.

In a wide window, I might have

```
|This is a long line of text.$      |
```

With extends and precedes set as you have, and shrinking the terminal a lot with the cursor at the beginning of the line (and `:set nowrap`):

```
|This is a long li>|
```

Hitting `$` will show the precedes as expected:

```
|<e of text.$      |
```

Moving to the middle:

```
|<long line of tex>|
```

(you can read more in the documentation for listchars, see `:help 'listchars'`):

As to seeing '>' instead of '>-' or '>---' for tabs, depending on where you are, a tab stop one character away from where the tab character is would result in a single character shown. Inserting a tab at the beginning (and wider window):

```
|>---This is a long line of text.$   |
```

adding 'ab'

```
|ab>-This is a long line of text.$   |
```

Adding 'c'

```
|abc>This is a long line of text.$   |
```

The '>' in this case always shows where the tab character is, and the '-' shows what additional columns were skipped to reach the tab stop, if any.

Comment: Ah! The display of `>` instead of `>-` is the tab stop. It just so happens the example I used also has extends with `>`. They display the same, but they're not the same _found listchar_.